# Icon tag <i> in remote ajax call in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i want to use the new Icon  tag from bootstrap css to make a remote call in rails 3.1.1

Here is my original code:

```
<%=link_to(image_tag("/assets/icons/sub_blue_down.png", :class => "points_arrow"),        
vote_down_politician_path(pending_discussions, :politician_id  =>   
pending_discussions.politician_id), :remote=> true, :method => :post) %>
```

I want to use this:

```
<i class="icon-minus-sign"></i>
```

Instead of the image tag

Here is my attempt but doesn't work:

```
<%= link_to  ' <i class="icon-plus-sign"></i>', 
vote_up_politician_path(pending_discussions, :politician_id  =>    
pending_discussions.politician_id), :remote=> true, :method => :post%>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be using this syntax instead:

```
<%= link_to vote_up_politician_path(pending_discussions, :politician_id  =>    
pending_discussions.politician_id), :remote=> true, :method => :post do%>
  <i class="icon-plus-sign"></i>
<% end %>
```

More info: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to

Answer (score 4):

You should also be able to use content_tag for this. Although this example doesn't do a remote call, it does use link_to and the glyph icons:

```
<%= link_to(content_tag(:i, nil, class: "icon-remove-sign"), 
  adcard_path(adcard), data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, 
  method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-mini') %>
```

In my case this was an address card with a delete button. Just another way, I think, and it might help someone else.

content_tag reference: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper/content_tag

Comment: That's true. I never thought of using the content_tag. Thanks for the info!